# Storage space under stairs

Tags: stairs, load-bearing, support

I am looking to finish the area under the stairs. There are two diagonal beams under the landing step. Can these be removed or do they contribute to the integrety of the staircase?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

they are contributing to strength .but can probably be replaced by a plywood bracing panel where the stairs overlap
[image]